# Удаление пользователя из базы данных бота телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

**Всем хорошего дня, утра, ночи.**

Разрабатываю телеграмм-бота на библиотеке telebot. Столкнулся с проблемой, при которой бот не делает рассылку всем пользователям, если кто-то из них остановил бота.

У меня есть база данных (текстовый файл с ID), в который добавляются пользователи после запуска бота, причем записываются без повторений, с этим все окей.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    if not message.chat.id in joinUser:
        join = open("join.txt", "a")
        join.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        joinUser.add(message.chat.id)
        join.close()
```

После чего я хочу сделать рассылку всем подписавшимся, открываю файл с ID и отсылаю всем по порядку из этого файла сообщение и тут возникает проблема, если человек отписался, то его ID из базы не удаляется и бот виснет над отправкой этого сообщения и не отсылает никому.

```
bot.message_handler(commands=["rs"])
def mess(message):
    if ADMIN == message.chat.id:
        for user in joinUser:
            bot.send_message(user,message.text[message.text.find(" "):])
```

В связи с этим вопрос, как можно проверить, что пользователь остановил бота и удалить его из БД ?

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать mysql для этого.
А вообще когда человек отписывается от бота тебе приходит апдейт, который ты можешь словить и удалить бота из своей «бд»